# How to change this program to print in order of patient name and urgency?

Tags: c

I tried to write a program that would indicate the sequence of steps in the order of the patient's name and urgency. But I don't know how to fill out the inputs and print the output again.

This is an example of input-output:

[image: This is an example of input-output]

This is an incomplete code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define fi 1000
int w;
char e;
struct quier {
    int data[fi];
    int front, near;
    int overflow;
    int underflow;
    char title[fi];
};

void enqueue(struct quier *quier, int a, char b) {
    if (quier -> near >- fi - 1) {
        quier -> overflow = 1;
    }
    else {
        quier -> near++;
        quier -> data[quier -> near] = a;
        quier -> title[quier -> near] = b;
        }
}

void dequeue(struct quier *quier) {
    if (quier -> front == quier -> near) {
        quier -> underflow = 1;
   }
    else {
        quier -> front++;
        w = quier -> data[quier -> front];
        e = quier -> title[quier -> front];
    }
}

int main() {
    struct quier quier;
    quier.front = -1;
    quier.near -1;
    quier.overflow = 0;
    quier.underflow = 0;

    int x, i, v;
    char k;
    scanf("%d", &x);
    for (i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        scanf("&c %d", &k, &v);
        enqueue(&quier, v, k);
    }
}
```

Comment: _" This is an example of input-output."_ What, the real output you got, or the one you want? _"This is an incomplete code."_ What's missing? What do you want readers to do for you? This is a very unclear question.

Comment: I think there is a typo `scanf("%c %d", &k, &v);` instead of `scanf("&c %d", &k, &v);`

Comment: @AditiRawat I also see one instance of `>-` where `->` was clearly intended…

Answer (score 1):

First like notice Aditi Rawat it is a typo in `scanf` should be `scanf("%c %d", &k, &v);`

When you use `scanf` you shouldn't forget about one thing, about whitespace char '\n' in buffer. When you get input in your first `scanf` to read a value for your loop and press "Enter" button, it puts in buffer '\n' char then later in `for` loop first char read from `scanf` its a '\n'. You should clear input buffer to get correct value. Here some example:

write a function to clear buffer and call it after each `scanf`:

```
 void clear_buff(void) 
    {
       while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF)
           ;
    }
```

One way around the problem is to put a blank space before the conversion specifier in the format string:

```
scanf(" %c", &c);
```

The blank in the format string tells scanf to skip leading whitespace, and the first non-whitespace character will be read with the %c conversion specifier.

Or just use `getchar();` after `scanf();`

Another mistake that I find:

Loot at `quier.near -1;` where is your  initializer char `=` ?

In that statement: `if (quier -> near >- fi - 1)`, I think you mean `if (quier -> near > fi - 1)`.

And `#define fi 1000` should be in uppercase. It's a convention, and makes reading and understanding code easier. It's not required, but recommended.

After that changes, I get output which I expect:

```
A 5
B 6
..etc
```

Also when you write program that take some data from user, always check it and think what should you do if your input would be incorrect? You just send error message and close your program or user should make another try?

I think it would be enough to figure out what is wrong in your program. If I make mistake somewhere please correct me.